# Object reference is not set into instance of an object

Tags: c#

I am retrieving data from database table.

By giving input as 1 in

```
textbox1(voucherno)-->damagedetail = 
                      web.getdamageddetail(Convert.ToInt32(voucherno.Text));
```

I want get *branchno* as output in textbox2(branchno)

```
branchno.Text = damagedetail.branchno.ToString();
```

but am getting error

> Object reference is not set into instance of an object.

Check my second line.

Is second line coding correct?

Comment: http://www.objectreference.net/post/Object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object.aspx

Comment: Your question is incredibly hard to read. Please put some effort into formatting it and rephrasing it in correct English.

Comment: Please use paragraphs and line breaks next time, it was almost impossible to read your question

Comment: branchno.text=damagedetail.branchno.tostring();...weather this line retrive branchno from database??

Answer (score 3):

`damagedetail.branchno` is null.

Try this:

```
if (damagedetail.branchno != null)
    branchno.Text = damagedetail.branchno;
else
    branchno.Text = "abcd";
```

Answer (score 0):

Either your object property is not filled thus when you retrive the value "branchno" from the object the value is equal to null, or your not filling the property in your "getdamageddetail" method